# Could not find a getter for password in class

Tags: java, web-services, restlet-2.0

I am writing REST services using Java RESTLET .

I have my User class here :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idUser", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 255)
    private Long idUser;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String password;
public Object setValue(Object input) {

    Object fieldValue = ((input == null) ? JSONObject.NULL.toString()
            : input);
    return fieldValue;
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setUserPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return username ;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.username = userName;
}





public Long getidUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContactFirstName() {
        return contactFirstName;
    }

    public void setContactFirstName(String contactFirstName) {
        this.contactFirstName = contactFirstName;
    }

    public String getContactLastName() {
        return contactLastName;
    }

    public void setContactLastName(String contactLastName) {
        this.contactLastName = contactLastName;
    }

    public String getContactEmail() {
        return contactEmail;
    }

    public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail) {
        this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
    }

    public String getContactMobile() {
        return contactMobile;
    }

    public void setContactMobile(String contactMobile) {
        this.contactMobile = contactMobile;
    }

    public String getContactPhone() {
        return contactPhone;
    }

    public void setContactPhone(String contactPhone) {
        this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
    }

    public String getContactAddress() {
        return contactAddress;
    }

    public void setContactAddress(String contactAddress) {
        this.contactAddress = contactAddress;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Timestamp createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Timestamp getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Timestamp updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

}
```

My User.hbm.xml files looks like .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="persistence.entity.User" table="user"> 
    <id name="idUser" type="long" unsaved-value="null">
        <column name="idUser" not-null="true"/>
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
        <property name="userName">
            <column name="username" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="password">
            <column name="password" not-null="true" />
        </property>         

        <property name="status">
            <column name="status" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="type">
            <column name="type" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate">
            <column name="createdDT" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="updatedDate">
            <column name="updatedDT" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="name">
            <column name="name" length="255" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="contactFirstName">
            <column name="contactFirstName" length="255" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="contactLastName">
            <column name="contactLastName" length="255" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="contactEmail">
            <column name="contactEmail" length="255" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="contactMobile">
            <column name="contactMobile" length="32" not-null="false" />
        </property>     
        <property name="contactPhone">
            <column name="contactPhone" length="32" not-null="false" />
        </property>     
        <property name="contactAddress">
            <column name="contactAddress" not-null="false" />
        </property>     

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have clerly defined the getter ans  setter in my User.java file .

But when I am running this code I am getting the error

```
 Could not find a getter for password in class tecd.persistenc.entity.User
```

I don't know what I am missing plz help me out

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Plz check now  file was too big so I did nt paste the complete code last time

Comment: thanks coding first time in java it helps me lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared getter and setter for `password` like this:

```
public String getUserPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setUserPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

I think it should be like this (no "User" in it):

```
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Those are the standard "bean"-style names for a `password` field.